# Fedora - Python import selinux cannot find selinux_current_policy_path

Tags: linux, fedora, python, fedora-17

When I run any python script that does `import selinux` (such as `system-config-users`) I get the following error:

```
ImportError: /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/selinux/_selinux.so: undefined symbol: selinux_current_policy_path
```

I think it must be something that I uninstalled at one time. But I don't have a clue what to install to fix it.

How do I fix it/What packages do I need to install?

Comment: sorry for offtop question, but how did you managed to find any docs to Python SELinux API? I really can not find anything.

Comment: @VitalyIsaev Actually, as a matter of fact, I don't even know Python. I didn't even look for API docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say which FC you're running, there was a bug in libselinux recently. Run `yum update libselinux` to update your version.

Comment: I am running Fedora 18 (64-bit). `libselinux` is installed and latest version.

Comment: Fixed it. Did `sudo yum reinstall libselinux`. For some reason I never thought of that. You suggesting updating it made me think of reinstalling it, therefore I am accepting your answer.